# jquery autocomplete dont return suggestions data onselec

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have input with id aktForm_tiekejas and is jquery autocomplete code:

```
$('#aktForm_tiekejas').autocomplete({
serviceUrl: '_tiekejas.php',
width: 185,
deferRequestBy: 0,
noCache: true,
onSelect: function(suggestion) {alert('You selected:'+suggestion.value+','+suggestion.data);}
});
```

_tiekejas.php:

```
<?php
include("../Setup.php");
$query = ($_GET['query']);
$reply = array();
$reply['query'] = $query;
$reply['suggestions'] = array();
$reply['data'] = array();
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id,pavadinimas FROM sarasas_tiekejas WHERE pavadinimas LIKE '%$query%' ORDER BY pavadinimas ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
 $reply['suggestions'][] = $row['pavadinimas'];
 $reply['data'][] = $row['id'];
}
mysql_close();
echo json_encode($reply);
?>
```

If query is 'vac' php returns from server:

```
{"query":"vac","suggestions":["UAB Vivacitas"],"data":["866"]}
```

but

```
alert('You selected:'+suggestion.value+','+suggestion.data);
```

doesn't alert data (866)

why?...

Answer (score 0):

Probably because suggestion.value doesn't exist. Looking at your JSON response code I can see the suggestion.data but no suggestion.value. Since JS will be looking for a value that doesn't exist it will throw an error. Also you're missing out the array for the second part of the return. Try this:

```
alert('You selected: '+suggestion.data[0]);
```

If you need to iterate through your data subsets do something like:

```
for(i in suggestion.data){
    alert('You selected: '+suggestion.data[i]);
}
```

Comment: I get alert "You selected:"UAB Vivacitas",NULL

Comment: Hmmm. I assume you didn't put the code I gave you to get that alert? I would have thought it to be: suggestion.suggestions[0] to get that. Have you tried then with your original code: alert('You selected:'+suggestion.value+','+suggestion.data[0]); ??